# Gitlab runner and keychain

Tags: linux, ssh, gitlab, keychain

Recently I have configured a Gitlab Runner on a VM and I wanted to add keychain on that VM to allow runner to execute commands like scp or SSH without exposing my SSH passphras (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/)

And when I install gitlab-multi-runner (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html) I see a new folder "`gitlab-runner`" in my `/home`.

So I added a password to this user (passwd command), edit its .bash_profile as described in the link above, and generate new SSH keys.

My runner is working fine, my .gitlab-ci.yml can execute scp commands like this :

```
scp jon.doe YOUR_LOGIN@DEV_SERVER_ADDRESS:/var/www/
```

No passphrase required / exposed.

So here my questions:

1. Is it safe to configure runner like this ?
2. Is there an official or better way, to do what i want ? (use SSH and SCP safely with a gitlab-runner)

I think there should be no problem, but I'm not an expert in Linux and SSH so...

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on askubuntu and here is the answer: (It could be useful to someone, one day...):

[Answer of Jakuje](https://askubuntu.com/a/858766/628979)

> If only you are running the jobs it is ok.
>
> If somebody else (you don't trust) can push any arbitrary command into your `.gitlab-cy.yml`, he can basically run any arbitrary code on your virtual machine and on your other machine (which is certainly not what you want).
>
> You should restrict your remote user `YOUR_LOGIN` on your dev server to do the minimum needed by `ForceCommand` (`scponly` or just the forced command to `scp` into specific directory), block port forwarding and possibly use chroot.

And for those who need information on ForceCommand, [you can follow this link](https://passingcuriosity.com/2014/openssh-restrict-to-sftp-chroot/)